# Optimizing a MySQL Join Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select * 
 from products as p
 left join files as f on f.contentid = p.productid
   where 
     p.state = 'active' AND 
     p.price > 0 order by p.created DESC 
   LIMIT 2200
```

Currently, this query takes about 1.7 seconds for 2200 rows. What I don't understand is, why does this time not decrease when I change the limit from 2200 to 10, and more importantly, what I can do to speed it up?

Comment: Are your ID fields indexed (contentid, productid)?

Comment: Do you need all fields of table products?

Comment: Time to order the data is the same for 10, 200, 2200 and all the rows. First data will be ordered then limit will be applied.

Comment: `SELECT p.field1, p.field2, p.fieldn FROM products p, files f WHERE f.contentid = p.productid AND p.state = 'active' AND p.price > 0 ORDER BY p.created DESC LIMIT 2200`

Comment: If you don't need every field from the two tables, you may also want to consider selecting the specific fields (instead of *) to reduce the size of the returned rows. That's helped me in situations in the past (especilly text fields).

Comment: Yes, I need all fields, and I think Stealth has directed me in the right direction (until today, this bachelor's degree com-sci student is ashamed to admit he never knew about indexes...)

Comment: Can anyone explain why the "limit" decrease doesnt affect the speed?

Comment: Give us `SHOW CREATE TABLE products` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
EXPLAIN select * 
 from products p
 left join files f on f.contentid = p.productid
   where 
     p.state = 'active' AND 
     p.price > 0 order by p.created DESC 
   LIMIT 2200
```

to see what indexes you need

Comment: + Options
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  p  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 1577  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE  f  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 1595

Comment: As I see  `possible_keys` column is null, so you got no possible keys for the query to use. Try to add indexes for `files` `contentid` and for `products` `productid`

Comment: I did that, it fixed the problem, but I'm unsure as to how to use explain. It ended up not giving me the answer... or at least, I don't know how to make sense of it...

Comment: @RD Here is a tutorial about explain http://www.eecho.info/Echo/database/using-explain/

Answer (score 5):

By adding [**INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on `files [contentid]` and `products [productid]`, it can speed up your query.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I just play with the query to see what minimizes runtime the best. If necessary, work out the problem using Relational Algebra and look for places to optimize from there. Here's my suggestion:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM products as p, files f
    WHERE f.contentid = p.productid 
    AND p.state = 'active'
    AND p.price > 0 
    ORDER BY p.created DESC
    LIMIT 2200
```